# pam: action on (unsuccessful) login

Tags: login, pam

I know how to execute an action on login, by adding a line to `/etc/profile`. But that only gets executed, if the login was successful. I would like to have action executed even when login fails. For example run a script `script.sh`.

I suspect, this can be set up in `pam`, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with `pam_exec` module and some `PAM` trickery. `PAM` configuration is usually very different across distributions so you will have to understand your configuration and try to tweak it.

For Debian (tested with 7.1) edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (comments left out for clarity)

- before

  ```
  auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so nullok_secure
  auth    requisite                     pam_deny.so
  auth    required                      pam_permit.so
  ```
- after

  ```
  auth    [success=2 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so nullok_secure
  auth    optional                      pam_exec.so /common-auth-pam_exec
  auth    requisite                     pam_deny.so
  auth    required                      pam_permit.so
  ```

What is actually happing, is that in case `pam_unix.so` succeeds, it will skip 2 following modules and jump to the `pam_permit.so` which will always succeed. In case of authentication failure `PAM` continues with execution of our script first, followed by `pam_deny`. That one will always fail, and because it has `requisite` control flag set no other module will be executed.

For completeness, program spawned by `pam_exec` runs with real user ID of the calling process (`setuid` option makes it run with effective user ID) and the process environment looks like this

```
PAM_SERVICE=login
PAM_RHOST=
PAM_USER=<username_here>
PAM_TYPE=auth
PAM_TTY=/dev/tty1
```

Comment: I have just realized that I can use `pam_exec.so /bin/echo`, but `pam_exec.so /bin/echo > /tmp/foo` does not work (nothing happens). Do you know why?

Comment: @MartinVegter That is because the `>` character is a redirect operator, which is supported in shells. PAM is not calling a shell to run the command, though - it's just calling the command directly. You could try to manually spool up a shell with `pam_exec.so /bin/sh -c 'echo > /tmp/foo'` and see if that works

Comment: Is there any way to redirect output to the current terminal prompting for authentication?

Comment: Edit: current hack involves echoing everything to `/dev/pts/{0,1,2}` but this is messy for obvious reasons. Second hack involves in `PTS=$(lsof | grep /dev/pts | grep -vP "(bash|lsof|grep)" > $tmp && awk '{print $NF}' $tmp | uniq; rm $tmp)` but there's no gaurantee on this one either.

Comment: Found it: `PTS=\`lsof | grep -P "^$PAM_TTY\s.*/dev/pts" | awk '{print $NF}'| uniq\``